# Search and Replace Header and Footer text in PowerPoint (.ppt and .pptx) using POI for Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, powerpoint

As it says in the title, I'm trying to search and replace header and footer text in new and old PowerPoint (.ppt and .pptx) files.  Here's a snippet of what I've done, but it doesn't work:

'''

```
   HSLFSlideShow document = null;

    try {
        document = new HSLFSlideShow(new FileInputStream(file));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage() + " : " + file.getName());
    }

    for (HSLFSlideMaster slideMaster : document.getSlideMasters()) {
        HeadersFooters headersFooters = slideMaster.getHeadersFooters();
        System.out.printf("header details:  Header %s and Footer %s.\n", headersFooters.getHeaderText(), headersFooters.getFooterText());
        headersFooters.setHeaderText(replacement);
        headersFooters.setFootersText(replacement);
        System.out.printf("NEW header details:  Header %s and Footer %s.\n", headersFooters.getHeaderText(), headersFooters.getFooterText());
    }
```

'''

After the file is saved (in code further down), I open the .ppt file and nothing has changed.

Comment: You know that headers exist only on notes and handout pages, right?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, John.  You are correct, perhaps this is why it doesn't work.  I think perhaps what I'm looking for a some search and replace regardless of where this text is.  Would you happen to have a link to a potential solution?